# GROCERY CRUD: set_rules callbacks not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, crud, grocery-crud

I tried to validate the password field using a callback function. But when I use the following code, all validations do not work any more WHEN I TYPE 1234 (callback condition). When I remove the validation which contains the callback function, other validations work perfectly..

This is my validation rules

```
    $crud->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'callback_valid_password');
    $crud->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');
    $crud->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
```

Here is my callback function

```
    function valid_password($str) {
    if ($str=="1234")
    {
        $crud->set_message('_valid_password', 'The field should be 1234');
        //do some pw validation
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    }
```

Please help me to find what is wrong here.. Thank you in advance
p.s - I am using php 5.4 version with the latest grocery crud version

Answer (score 1):

```
function valid_password($str) {
   if ($str=="1234")
   {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_password', 'The field should be 1234');
      //do some pw validation
      return FALSE;
   }
   else
   {
      return TRUE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling to find the solution, please follow the checklist.

> **Are you using CodeIgniter as MVC or HMVC?**

**1. HMVC**

(A) - Check if you have updated the file (***./application/libraries/Grocery_crud.php***) as suggested below.

(B) - Before "**__construct**" inside " "**class Grocery_CRUD extends grocery_CRUD_States**" add "***protected $hmvc;***"

(C) - Update "__construct" with as below:

```php
public function __construct($hmvc = null)
{
    $this->hmvc = $hmvc;
}
```

(D) - Update "form_validation" with as below:

```php
protected function form_validation()
{
    if ($this->form_validation === null) {
        $this->form_validation = new grocery_CRUD_Form_validation();
        if ($this->hmvc) $this->form_validation->CI = $this->hmvc;
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('form_validation');
        $ci->form_validation = $this->form_validation;
    }
    return $this->form_validation;
}
```

(E) - Use "**$crud = new Grocery_crud($this);**" instead "**$crud = new Grocery_crud();**" in your Controller.

(F) - **GC set_rules example:**

```php
$crud->set_rules("level_title", 'Level Title Label', 'trim|required|callback_unique_level_field_check');
```

(G) - **Callback method example:**

```php
public function unique_level_field_check ($level_title)
{
    if ( empty($level_title))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('unique_level_field_check', "Level Title Label should be unique");
            return FALSE;
        }
    return TRUE;
}
```

---

**2. MVC**

> Follow F & G only (above).

---

GroceryCRUD Forum: [See details here](https://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/3841-problem-with-callback-in-validation-rule/)